# Infinite-loop problems

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I was doing some challenges from Coding.Dojo algorithm challenges and I'm stuck at "The Final Countdown" challenge. So this is what I was asked to do:

> Give 4 parameters (param1, param2, param3, param4),print the multiples
> of param1, starting at param2 and extending to param3.If a multiple is
> equal to param4 then skip-don't print that one. Do this using a while.
> Given (3,5,17,9) print 6,12,5 (which are the multiples of 3 between 5
> and 17, except of the value 9).

The problem is that when I run my code it goes to an infinite loop. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong. Here's my code:

```js
function finalCount(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
  var i = param2;
  while (i <= param3) {
    if (i == param4) {
      continue;
    } else if (i % param1 == 0) {
      console.log(i);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
finalCount(3, 5, 17, 9)
```

Comment: I suspect that `if (i == param4)` you'll get into an infinite loop with the `continue` ;)

Comment: remove the `continue`

Comment: Step through the code line by line in a debugger to see where the infinite loop is. Once you understand what the problem is, you can start working out ways to solve it.

Comment: Please make your title more specific for more accurate Google indexing, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calling `continue` will put you into an infinite loop because `i` does not get incremented by one.

You can invert the check `i == param4` and put it into the second condition like this:

```js
  if (i % param1 == 0 && i != param4) {
      console.log(i);
    }
```